# Pyinstaller sys.executable wrong when copying the directory

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have built a application and bundled it with pyinstaller on Windows
Now I want to access the directory of the frozen application by calling

```
installdir = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
```

That works quite well for me except when I copy the whole directory to a different location

Then my installdir turns into this:

```
X:\Users\<user>\ZOMB~S0!
```

what it should look like is this:

```
X:\Users\<user>\Zombie_2020_01_22_17_09_25_PSL
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind found an answer. Windows was just shortening the path. To get the full path, I can use

```
installDir = win32api.GetLongPathName(os.path.dirname(sys.executable))
```